# best way to specify packages location on linux machine

Tags: java, linux, servlets, classpath

I have several servlets that import many packages:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.security.*; 
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.naming.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;  
import javax.naming.NamingException;  
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;  
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult; 
import javax.naming.ldap.*; 
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;  
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext; 
import javax.naming.directory.*;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.ModificationItem; 
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator; 
import javax.crypto.SecretKey; 
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher; 
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.net.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

My CLASSPATH has folowing in it:

```
echo $CLASSPATH
.:/usr/lib64/jvm/java:/usr/lib64/logi-lib:/usr/share/java:/usr/share/tomcat6/lib
```

So, my question is, do I have to specify each path to each package individually when compiling and running these servlets and do I need to change anything in web.xml file other than below code?

```
   ...
    <servlet>
          <servlet-name>SendEmail</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>SendEmail</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>SendResetEmailLink</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>SendResetEmailLink</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SendEmail</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SendEmail</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SendResetEmailLink</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SendResetEmailLink</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    ...
```

Comment: First - that many imports is code smell. Your classes are doing too much. As to your question - this cannot be answered without know how you compile the code. Your `CLASSPATH` variable may or may not have _any_ effect depending on the web server. Java web applications get their classpath from the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in the war.

Comment: Also, in general, CLASSPATH is usually not a great idea; prefer either `-cp` but better yet, use a build tool like Maven or Ant etc. That's a terrifyingly long import chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling and running are two completely different things.

For compilation, these classes must be in the classpath associated with compiler, usually in most of the tools called build path. You should really use a dev tool for building, like for example Eclipse. There you will be able to easily specify all required jars. In your case just java runtime and Tomcat libraries.

For running they must be available for runtime environment, if you run servlets they need to be available for web container, either via jars in the container classpath or provided with your application. By a quick look, all imports you have should be provided by Tomcat without any additional jars.

> do I have to specify each path to each package individually?

No, usually you provide path to the jar (archive containing many packages).

As to your import list - if you provide * in import all classes in given package are already imported, so if you have:

```
import javax.naming.directory.*;

//then these are obsolete:
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;  
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult; 
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.ModificationItem; 

// however it is only on package level, not recursive so
import javax.naming.*;
// doesn't import automatically javax.naming.ldap.*; and you will need to provide it also
import javax.naming.ldap.*;
```

Good development tools will also detect imports that are not used by your class and you will be able to remove them. e.g. you rather not use `java.awt.*` while working with servlets ;)